# Como organizar um projeto laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

Estou começando agora com Laravel 4 e gostaria de saber como vocês organizam o projeto de vocês? referente a classes de controllers e models.

Por exemplo, no meu caso vou ter uma área administrativa e vou ter o site(front), gostaria de separar as partes. No CodeIgniter eu usava o HMVC e no Laravel?

Answer (score 2):

Como o Laravel 4.X usa o composer e o PHP 5.3+ (o laravel4.2 exige o php5.4+),
geralmente se cria uma pasta dentro de app assim:

[image]

Criei a pasta "Hub", e adicionei ela ao composer.json assim:

[image]

Obs.: É necessário rodar o comando "composer dump-autoload" para os novos arquivos criados.
e você usa a estrutura "app" default do laravel para o frontend.

A forma de chamá-los é "\Hub\SuaPasta\SuaClasse".